# "Мати", чи "матір"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Допоможіть розібратись.
Вживання слова "матір" замість слова "мати" там, де має бути слово в називному відмінку, це:
а) однозначно помилка;
б) допускається, оскільки це одне і те ж;
в) можливе тільки в сталих висловах (наприклад, "Матір Божа");
г) [інший, не передбачений мною варіант].

Answer (score 2):

Як в-же [відповѣв і навѣв](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/7161/585) *Sasha*, за вжитком чутливо домінуїть *мати*, тому слово *матір* будить видѣляти ся, а отже можливо мати різні відтѣнки.

*Sasha* акцентовав лише на літературну складову. Хоча слово зустрѣчаїться і в правовій складові, наприклад біля *мати-одиночка* можна подибовати і *матір-одиночка*.

> [Головне територіальне управління юстиції у Хмельницкій області, Волочиське районне управління юстиції](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6H4rqMco060J:https://justice-km.gov.ua/uploads/files/ohorona%2520praci%2520zhinok.doc&cd=15&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua&lr=-lang_ru)
>
> […] Якщо *матір-одиночка*, то вона змушена погоджуватися на будь-яку роботу, незважаючи на умови праці. […]

І частѣше [*матір-одиначка*](//www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%22+site%3A*.gov.ua&lr=-lang_ru&newwindow=1&tbs=lr%3A-lang_1ru), де через *а*. Хоча, тут слово теж можна сприймати як ознаку шчо-сь урочистого.

Як-шчо ж зараз мода на корпуси, як для доводів на вжиток, то тоді можна згадати старѣшу форму як *матѣрь*. Наступний пошук, шчо просто узятиь з *Sasha*, але чому-сь їм не пояснений, бо наче кожен маїть розумѣти і вмѣти в таке, менѣ [не допоміг](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&tab=advanced&queryselector=cql&attrs=word%2Clemma&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.locCode%2C%3Ddoc.original%2C%3Ddoc.publicationCity%2C%3Ddoc.publicationYear%2C%3Ddoc.publisher%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.translator&default_attr=lemma&cql=%5Btag%3D%22adj%3Af%3A.*%22%20%26%20word%3D%22.*%D0%B0%D1%8F%3F%22%20%26%20word!%3D%22%D1%82%D0%B0%22%5D%20%5Bword%3D%22%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8C%22%5D&selection=%7B%7D&showresults=1&fullcontext=1&f_tab=advanced&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22cql%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%5Btag%3D%22adj%3Af%3A.*%22%20%26%20word%3D%22.*%D0%B0%D1%8F%3F%22%20%26%20word!%3D%22%D1%82%D0%B0%22%5D%20%5Bword%3D%22%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8C%22%5D%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22cqlrow%22%2C%22cql%22%3A%22%5Btag%3D%22adj%3Af%3A.*%22%20%26%20word%3D%22.*%D0%B0%D1%8F%3F%22%20%26%20word!%3D%22%D1%82%D0%B0%22%5D%20%5Bword%3D%22%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8C%22%5D%22%2C%22default_attr%22%3A%22lemma%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A2527%7D%5D):

```
[tag="adj:f:.*" & word=".*ая?" & word!="та"] [word="матірь"]
```

Тобто замѣнив *матір* на *матірь*, однак корпус не маїть такоѣ леми чи або-шчо — не пояснюїть і викидаїть помилку *Nothing found* [*пер.* нічого не знайдено]. Тому покладати ся на корпуси не дуже варто, бо вони також можуть не мати банально і бази. Але як-шчо просто шукати за [`матірь`](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&tab=basic&keyword=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8C&attrs=word%2Clemma&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.locCode%2C%3Ddoc.original%2C%3Ddoc.publicationCity%2C%3Ddoc.publicationYear%2C%3Ddoc.publisher%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.translator&showresults=1&fullcontext=1&f_tab=advanced&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8C%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8C%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A7107%7D%5D), тобто це по сутѣ як в Ґуґлѣ, але з меншою базою, то будуть декотрі приклади, втч. сучасних, де можна навѣть побачити Андруховича. Корпус Ляйпціґа маїть більше [сучасних](//corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8C) прикладів.

Чи теж можу написати таке? Он приклади з літератури і навѣть сучасноѣ!

> Це однозначно не помилка, адже таке слово вживається в літературі (і не лише в релігійному контексті).

На жаль, нѣ, хоча би через те, шчо правопис забороняїть писати *рь*, як-шчо далѣ не голосна чи то не са́ме слово *Горький* або похідні. Тобто тут однозначно який-сь ніянс.

Висновок? На жаль, я не настільки смѣливий, тому його не будить. Можу лише припустити, шчо саме слово *матір* не є помилковим, пак єсть в згаданому тут словницѣ СУМ-20, але скорѣш за всього мати йме забарвєння різного характера, переважно діялектного або архаѣчного, де через друге також урочистого чи реліґійного, а тому можливо і іронічного. Тобто схоже, шчо вживати як *мати* можна, але бажано покладати ся на контекст і чи його зрозумѣють так само гинші.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>[Попередня версія](/revisions/7161/1) цієї відповіді була помилковою, адже мовила про знахідний відмінок, а не називний. Дякую [Yellow Sky](/u/66) за уважність!</sub>

Це однозначно не помилка, адже таке слово [вживається](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&cql=%5Btag%3D%22adj%3Af%3A.*%22%20%26%20word%3D%22.*%D0%B0%D1%8F%3F%22%20%26%20word!%3D%22%D1%82%D0%B0%22%5D%20%5Bword%3D%22%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80%22%5D&showresults=1) в літературі (і не лише в релігійному контексті):

> Бач, пашпорта мені треба було в вашій волості виправляти, бо покійна матір моя була родом з сього села; от мене й справили до діда («У темряві», Михайло Старицький, 1892).

> Галю обхопив жах від думки, що вона може загубити в очереті Миколку і бідна матір так притиснула його до себе, що хлопець кричав не вгаваючи («Зруйноване гніздо», Адріан Кащенко, 1914).

> А вдома його стара матір уже упорала грядки на городі, від них пахтіло паром («Земля в цвіту», Михайло Івченко, 1924).

Проте протягом усього часу його вживали вкрай рідко:
[image]

[«Словник української мови» у 20 томах каже](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=50114&page=1583), що це слово не нейтральне, а застаріле та урочисте. Я теж вважаю, що це слово має специфічне стилістичне забарвлення. Хоча я не певен, що примітка «заст., уроч.» у СУМ-20 досконало точно описує це специфічне забарвлення. Але зводити його лише до сталих конструкцій, по-моєму, тим більше не варто.

<sub>Приклади та графіки взято з «Генерального регіонально анотованого корпусу української мови» (версії 16).</sub>

Comment: Ви геть не зрозуміли питання. Питання ж було саме про **називний** відмінок, бо за літературним стандартом _мати_ — це називний, а _матір_ — знахідний відмінок. От і питання: а чи правильно вживати форму знахідного відмінка _матір_ у значенні називного відмінка? Ви ж наводите приклади, де _матір_ вжито в значенні **знахідного** відмінка, а про таке природне вживання питання ж не було, як і не було питання про частоту вживання слова _мати_ в різних відмінках.

Comment: @YellowSky, дякую, Ви праві! (З якогось дива під час написання відповіді я мислив, що коли називний _мати_, то й знахідний має бути _мати_, а коли називний _матір_, то й знахідний має бути _матір_. Звісно, це не так. Хоча, як не дивно, іноді й у знахідному кажуть _мати_: «Не покладу, бо ся бою, бо лихую мати маю, лиху бо я мати маю, буде бити, добре знаю» — але це рідкість і мова не про це.) Відредагував відповідь (хоча, можливо, варто було вилучити й написати нову).

Answer (score -3):

я б відповів Б. оскільки у слово "матір" є у словниках, хоча і на 2ому місці після "мати", як хочете, так і кажіть

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Я з Вами згоден, але варто було б послатися на відповідні словники (в ідеалі — зацитувати відповідні словникові статті).